# Why can't some songs be played with Music?

Tags: ios, apple-music

I would like to know why some songs in Apple Music can't get played in an album or in a list and can be played individually.

I will show how I see some albums:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means Apple doesn't have the rights to stream the song to you, whether that be a locale-specific problem or because the song is Album Only on the iTunes Store.

Comment: What I don't understand is that these songs could be played individually but not as an album.

Comment: Those tunes are probably also on some other album which is licensed for Apple Music.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this "dimming out" has nothing to do with your internet, wi-fi, or cellular connection--and for what it's worth, I have seen this in iOS 8.4.1 on my phone and in iTunes 12.2.2.25 on both Mac or PC, both ethernet connected and via wi-fi.

Although I suppose it is possible, it also does not make sense that Apple would not get the rights to certain songs on certain albums; so far, the songs that I haven't been able to play seem completely random.

Finally, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with songs I own vs. songs I "borrow" from Apple Music.

Basically, it doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me when Apple Music wouldn't work fully without wifi, not allowing me to listen to most songs.

Go to the settings app, iTunes & App Store and turn on Use Mobile Data.

Hope this works for your problem!

Answer (score 0):

This also could mean that your internet connection is offline or very weak. Apple Music is able to cache recently played songs, and therefore these will be able to play directly from the storage on your device. When the Internet connection becomes stronger, these greeted out songs may be able to be streamed like the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

I have recognized that it is not possible to stream those songs on Apple Music, which are marked also as "Album Only" in iTunes Store. It seems that it has to do something with rights. It is definitely not a connectivity issue.