# Why are many songs just not played in iTunes in Apple Music? How to force them to be played?

Tags: itunes, apple-music, pc

I've installed iTunes on PC and have registered with Apple Music. I've started playing an album. But most of the songs are just not being played. Only one-three songs for an album are playable. What kind of issue with iTunes/Apple/Apple Music is that? How to force iTunes to play them?

Here are screenshots of the difference.

- A song that is playable has a grey color slider:

[image]

- Songs that iTunes doesn't play have blue color slider. iTunes just freezes on those songs and never goes to the the next song in an album:

[image]

And no any hints except these about why Apple Music doesn't play songs.

Similar questions:

[iTunes - Apple Music - songs are not playing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213698/itunes-apple-music-songs-are-not-playing)

[Why can't some songs be played with Music?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195457/why-cant-some-songs-be-played-with-music)

Comment: This happens a lot for me. If it's an option on PC Apple Music, allow a larger playback cache so it can store more music locally. Also try downloading songs for offline listening.

Comment: The blue line (@Green's second picture) happens to me when I listen to songs 'online'. When I download them offline, that problem doesn't happen to me. Have you tried downloading the album offline?

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Discussion has a similar question.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7133462?tstart=0)

They suggest that you change your DNS. Try using the Google Public DNS.

I would also suggest you to restart your router once.